# Replace a content in a Text file in python

Tags: python, python-regex

From a text file want to replace the content to *
for example in a text file, I want to replace all the content after the password:

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex after reading and before writing.

```
import re
pattern = 'password'
string = file.read()
result = re.split(pattern, string)
newtext=result[0]
```